# Twitter Bootstrap: How do I align section in navbar to right?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Here is the plunker - http://plunker.co/edit/YplsPFRiYo4jjbi7HcYV?p=preview

**Required?**
- The User Settings dropdown should be on the extreme right side
- The User setting should look like another section like other Link, and not as button

How do I do that?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I worked for a while and was able to get it displayed on right side, but nothing happens on click

http://plunker.co/edit/YplsPFRiYo4jjbi7HcYV?p=preview

Comment: I don't really see the "User settings dropdown" that you mention, but I know the bootstrap css has a ".pull-right" attribute. Will that help?

Comment: I tried something meanwhile, please see my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include JQuery in your index.html file, JQuery is a dependency of the bootstrap.js

http://plunker.co/edit/dePLLK?p=preview

```
<head>
   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```